# How can i code when SELECT html control has only one value

Tags: jquery, html

I am facing a scenario where select control is populating with values using php and I have coded against onChange when any value is changed then the changed value populate in the textbox.

BUT When select control has only one value then onchange does not work because there is only  one value. How can I catch that value and populate in the textbox when the select control has only one value..

Comment: the same way you handle it when there are multiple `options` and the user hasn't selected one yet.. do you use the first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get value of the only select element on jquery [**document.ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event by calling [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function on select object.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ftyeX/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectedVal = $('#yourSelectId').val();
});
```